# SciDB vs OLAP cube

Tags: data-analysis

I am working on good retrieval mechanism for big data systems. I am of view that multidimensional structures could be of great use for aggregations and querying .  Multidimensional structures  as mentioned in theory/products could replace the need of OLAP CUBE.

Here is some data size info residing into data-warehouse and it is approx. around 1 trillion per month and some time even more and having rolling window of 1 month or greater, it depends per client. I used to write reports,sub-reports and calculate aggregates using sub-reports , and also used analytical and analytical aggregate function to accomplish the reports/query.

Can some one share the thoughts on it.

Regards,

Comment: It is a little unclear what you are asking.  When you say big data systems how big do you mean?  What types of queries and aggregations are you going to do?

Comment: updated the post